# Disable Total Commander Open Folder Window In Explorer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, total-commander

Sometimes, Total Commander opens some folders in Explorer. I don't know the reason, it might be due to some bug in my own autohotkey definitions.

Anyway, how can I disable Total Commander to open folder windows in explorer at all?

Comment: Can you give examples of which folders are opened in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

Create a .reg file like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]
@="TC"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TC]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TC\command]
@="$PATH_TO_TOTALCMD %1"
```

where *$PATH_TO_TOTALCMD* is path where is the totalcmd.exe located. In my setup it's "c:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.EXE".

This will tell Windows, that the default handler for Folder exploring is Total Commander.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are experiencing exactly what @RonK says. You can avoid it typing "cd " and the folder name. Then enter. When you type just a folder name and press enter the command is executed and such as your command is a path windows will open it in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a lot of info on this question, but it can happen when you write a path in the command line and press Enter - `Total Commander` will "run" the command, and since it is a path, `Windows` will interpret it as a request to open the `Windows Explorer` to that path.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if . is inadvertently hit on the keyboard, and then sometime later, you hit Enter.  Any typed character goes into the command shell.  Enter first processes what's in the command shell, before it is interpreted as a navigation command.  The result: an explorer window pops up.

You can tell if this is the cause by observing the path that the Explorer window is in.  If it is the same as one of the panes in Total Commander, then the above may be the culprit.