# How to avoid typing "cd " to open folder in Totalcmd?

Tags: windows-explorer, total-commander

I'm aware of why does Total Commander opens Windows Explorer when a folder name is typed and then enter is pressed. In fact, you can see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/455588/59114) to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/388364/disable-total-commander-open-folder-window-in-explorer/).

Also I've configured TC to open search dialog as soon as I type. So now, to open selected folder I need to type:

1. Right arrow (to go to the command bar).
2. Type: `cd .`
3. <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (TC writes selected folder name).
4. Enter to open.

It is really annoying. Is there any easiest way?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, why you simply can't use just Enter to go inside the folder? Why you have to type it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid running the Explorer, you can change in `Configuration -> Quick Search` the option to `'Letters - with search dialog'`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need steps 1 or 2.  Just Step 3 and 4 will open the folder in Explorer.

Not sure why the accepted answer is accepted -- your question makes it sound like you **want** to open a folder in Explorer, whereas the accepted answer is telling you how to **avoid** running Explorer.